# jhipster failed at npm install puppeteer when running ./mvnw

Tags: maven, npm, jhipster

hi i have generated jhipster application with the flowing configurations.

my `.yo.rc.json` file used for application generation is below

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "authenticationType": "oauth2",
    "baseName": "microapp",
    "blueprints": [],
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "creationTimestamp": 1659798467950,
    "cypressAudit": true,
    "cypressCoverage": false,
    "databaseType": "no",
    "devDatabaseType": "no",
    "devServerPort": 4200,
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "enableGradleEnterprise": false,
    "enableHibernateCache": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "jhipsterVersion": "7.9.2",
    "languages": ["en", "fr"],
    "messageBroker": false,
    "microfrontend": false,
    "microfrontends": [],
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "otherModules": [],
    "packageName": "com.labkit.microapp",
    "pages": [],
    "prodDatabaseType": "no",
    "reactive": false,
    "searchEngine": false,
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "serverSideOptions": [],
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "no",
    "skipCheckLengthOfIdentifier": false,
    "skipFakeData": false,
    "skipUserManagement": true,
    "testFrameworks": ["cypress", "cucumber"],
    "websocket": false,
    "withAdminUi": true
  }
}
```

I have generated maven monolithic application,  i have installed multiple versions of nodejs then end of with uninstalling all other versions. now i have only one version (16.16.0)installed , after generation npm install also failed, and npmw also failed , and mvnw also failed.

i have also generated gradle build. same issue in gradle projects as well.

```
[INFO] npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
[INFO] npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[INFO] npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
[INFO] npm WARN deprecated puppeteer@9.1.1: Version no longer supported. Upgrade to @latest
[INFO] npm ERR! code 1
[INFO] npm ERR! path V:\sagcloud\opensource\jhipster-tryout\vidhya-rocking\node_modules\pa11y\node_modules\puppeteer
[INFO] npm ERR! command failed
[INFO] npm ERR! command bash /C/Users/VDE/AppData/Local/Temp/install-34d9bb4d.sh
[INFO]
[INFO] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[INFO] npm ERR!     C:\Users\VDE\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-14T08_16_28_997Z-debug-0.log
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  06:34 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-14T13:52:42+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:npm (npm install) on project microapp: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

what could be the issue. please help

Comment: First thing to note: maven build does not use your globally installed version of nodejs, it uses a locally installed in version that is specified in pom.xml. Have you looked at the log file specified in the error? The error mentions bash but you're running on Windows, did you ever try to run it from Command Prompt or Powershell to use only standard shells?

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck on this too. These two lines are key:

```
[INFO] npm ERR! command failed
[INFO] npm ERR! command bash /C/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/...
```

Solution:

Deleting `.npmrc` file generated on the app and running `npm install` again on the app. That fixed the issue.

This recently was added by the Jhipster team. I guess they did not have Windows users in mind.